# How "refresh" a AJAX UpdatePanel from another form?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

If in the ASP Form "A" I have a Updatepanel ... How refresh this when click in a button of ASP Form "B".

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible, given all of the effort put in to make sure that the UpdatePanels are safe from xss attacks...  I'm pretty sure the contents of an UpdatePanel are only accessible/changeable from events within the same UpdatePanel.

Comment: You don't have to update from within the same update panel. You can do UpdatePanel1.Update() if its mode is set to conditional.

Comment: OK.   I wasn't sure, which is why it was a comment, and not an answer.  I know someone with a better answer would correct me and I'd learn this way.  Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help, chap :). I only found out a few weeks ago myself.

Answer (score 3):

As long as they are on the same page you can do it via javascript I think:

```
<div id="Container" onclick="__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '');">
```

Ref:  http://encosia.com/2007/07/13/easily-refresh-an-updatepanel-using-javascript/

Though I think in .Net having 2 forms on the same page is a little weird - only one can be *runat=server*

Comment: +1 for the "little weird"  that was my thought exactly, but I don't know @nelson's requirements.

Comment: I found this post searching for how to refresh an update panel from javascript, and this is exactly what I need. Great!

Answer (score 2):

You can just do `UpdatePanelId.Update()`?

I'm not sure it works between different forms. You'll need to set the UpdatePanel's update mode as `Conditional`.